# Correct regex returns null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this regex -

```
const liveEditingRegex = new RegExp('\`{3}example([\s\n\<A-Za-z\>=\"\/]*)\`{3}example', 'g');
```

and this text

````
# Box
## HTML block below
<blockquote>
  This is an example of a block with react markdown!
</blockquote>



```example
  <Box>
    <BoxHeader key="one">
        <BoxTitle key="two" title="Box Title"/>
    </BoxHeader>
    <BoxBody>
        <Text> This is a BoxBody </Text>
    </BoxBody>
    <BoxFooter>
        <Text> This is a Box Footer </Text>
    </BoxFooter>
  </Box>
```example
````

According to https://www.debuggex.com/, things work fine, but when I execute the code, I get that `match = null`.

Why?

Comment: When using `RegExp` constructor syntax, the backslashes need to be double-escaped. Or use Regex literal syntax `/\`{3}example([\s\n\<A-Za-z\>=\"\/]*)\`{3}example/g`

Comment: I was escaping the backticks?

Comment: No need of escaping backticks [`{3}example([\s\n\<A-Za-z\>=\"\/]*)`{3}example](https://regex101.com/r/lV8mW2/1)